# Embedded Google Map not working properly in IE

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I have a page on my site with a regular, embeded-from-Google Google Map. The map works fine on every browser but IE. The issue seems to come and go, but leans more toward not working than working.

[Link to test with just the map »](http://dev.magzalez.com/maptest)

When you visit the site with IE8 you get the map but no pin and no directions:

[image: Google Maps on IE8]

When you visit the site with IE7 you get the map and a loading dialog.

[image: Google Maps on IE7]

This is the JS error I get on IE:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Thu, 6 Oct 2011 14:39:55 UTC

Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 2093
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/371b/maps2/%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_act,mod_act_s,mod_actbr,mod_adf,mod_appiw,mod_mg,mod_mssvt,mod_rst,mod_strr%7D.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 228
Char: 65
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=9380+SW+152nd+St+Miami,+FL+33176&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=49.223579,96.152344&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=9380+SW+152nd+St,+Miami,+Florida+33176&t=m&ll=25.638431,-80.345249&spn=0.027083,0.048923&z=14&iwloc=A&output=embed
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I see the red pin on IE8 and I do not get any error.

Comment: Are you using IE8 for both browser and document mode? I have about as standard an IE8 install as you can get because I never use my Windows programs.

Comment: Well, today it is somehow different. I see this page in IE8. Then I click on the link in your post and get 'Page loading ...' and the same error as you describe. Then I click on the link 'Troubleshooting' and a Google page is displayed. Then I browse back and now your page is displayed with the red marker and without errors.

Comment: That's the strange thing. If you refresh you'll get one of a couple possibilities: 1) just the map, 2) loading... or 3) it'll work. On the first and second you'll see a JS error. On the third you will not.

Comment: I currently have the exact same problem.  Occasionally works in IE8, but mostly not.  Have tried some different doctypes per recommendation elsewhere, but no solution yet.

Comment: I also tried to change it from HTML5 to XHTML but no discernible difference.

Comment: It does work EVERY time when I click the 'troubleshooting guide' link and then go back.  Very strange.  I'll keep you posted if I find anything.

Comment: The Google Maps Twitter account told me to create a post in the Google Help Forum, so I did: [Embeded Google Map not working properly in IE](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?fid=7e6c7959493cd6cd0004aebb8d0af4d8&hl=en). I'll post back if I get anything from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps Twitter account told me to create a post in the Google Help Forum, so I did: [Embedded Google Map not working properly in IE](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=7e6c7959493cd6cd&hl=en&fid=7e6c7959493cd6cd0004af4ad0bc0a08).

Google then responded to my forum post about the issue saying they have pushed a fix to the problem.

[Embedded Google Map not working properly in IE](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=7e6c7959493cd6cd&hl=en&fid=7e6c7959493cd6cd0004af4ad0bc0a08)